# Tool to transform NMAP results to something RSA Archer consumes

Tags: xml, file-converter, dataflow

While nmap can write an XML file with `-oX` the fields do not map very cleanly to those that RSA Archer imports.  For example, for hardware in Archer Device Type is a required field, but that isn't something I've seen nmap try to produce.  Similarly, nmap may provide several candidate OSes, but Archer would only expect a single value.

So I can use a `data feed` in Archer to load the XML file from nmap, but it's not at all clear how to map the output to the input fields.  Is there either a set of options for either nmap or Archer (or a combination) that will work, or is there a tool that would help to convert the data from one to the other?

I have access to many OSes to run the solution on, though most of the work to date is being done on either a flavor of Linux (either an old Fedora or CentOS 7), and Windows (7 or 2008, though others could be available too).

If a tool exists for another platform, I would likely be able to get an instance of that to use.